# Why saving the access and refresh token on the client is not secure?

Tags: security, spring-cloud-gateway

Could you explan me why keeping access and refresh token on browser or mobile is not secure?
And scheme bellow is considered the safest.
[image]

Comment: This must be some kind of special case scenario. I would not call it safer. I would call the Edge Service a single point of failure. Hack this and you have hacked everyone and everything.